# spark cassandra connector problem using catalogs

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am following the instructions [found here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md) to connect my spark program to read data from Cassandra. Here is how I have configured spark:

```
val configBuilder = SparkSession.builder
  .config("spark.sql.extensions", "com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions")
  .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraUrl)
  .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", 9042)
  .config("spark.sql.catalog.myCatalogName", "com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraCatalog")
```

According to the documentation, once this is done I should be able to query Cassandra like this:

`spark.sql("select * from myCatalogName.myKeyspace.myTable where myPartitionKey = something")`

however when I do so I get the following error message:

```
mismatched input '.' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 43)

== SQL ==
select * from myCatalog.myKeyspace.myTable where myPartitionKey = something
----------------------------------^^^
```

When I try in the following format I am successful at retrieving entries from Cassandra:

```
val frame = spark
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("keyspace" -> "myKeyspace", "table" -> "myTable"))
  .load()
  .filter(col("timestamp") > startDate && col("timestamp") < endDate)
```

However this query requires a full table scan to be performed. The table contains a few million entries and I would prefer to avail myself of the predicate Pushdown functionality, which it would seem is only available via the SQL API.

I am using spark-core_2.11:2.4.3, spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.5.0 and Cassandra 3.11.6

Thanks!

Comment: what version of DataStax Spark Cassandra Connector
 are you using ?

Comment: @Srinivas 2.5.0, i'll add that into the question

Comment: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#configuring-catalogs-to-cassandra
The configuration looks different in the HowTo.

Comment: @SašaZejnilović there are a number of different ways to set config properties in spark, in the docs they state that all are equal: `To set up a catalog put the following configuration into your SparkSession configuration (or any other Spark Configuration file or Object)`

Comment: @Jewels I mean your conf paths look different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Catalogs API is available only in SCC version 3.0 that is not released yet. It will be released with Spark 3.0 release, so it isn't available in the SCC 2.5.0.  So for 2.5.0 you need to register your table explicitly, with `create or replace temporary view...`, as [described in docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/14_data_frames.md#example-creating-a-source-using-spark-sql):

```scala
spark.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW myTable
     USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
     OPTIONS (
     table "myTable",
     keyspace "myKeyspace",
     pushdown "true")""")
```

Regarding the pushdowns (they work the same for all Dataframe APIs, SQL, Scala, Python, ...) - such filtering will happen when your `timestamp` is the first clustering column.  And even in that case, the typical problem is that you may specify `startDate` and `endDate` as strings, not timestamp.  You can check by executing `frame.explain`, and checking that predicate is pushed down - it should have `*` marker near predicate name.

For example,

```scala
val data = spark.read.cassandraFormat("sdtest", "test").load()
val filtered = data.filter("ts >= cast('2019-03-10T14:41:34.373+0000' as timestamp) AND ts <= cast('2019-03-10T19:01:56.316+0000' as timestamp)")
val not_filtered = data.filter("ts >= '2019-03-10T14:41:34.373+0000' AND ts <= '2019-03-10T19:01:56.316+0000'")
```

the first `filter` expression will push predicate down, while 2nd (`not_filtered`) will require a full scan.

Comment: amazing! this is what worked.
Alex where can I find the docs for the current available version?

Comment: You can use the link from this answer - it's pointing to the `b2.5` branch... The same will be for 3.0 release, released docs are in the `b3.0`, as `master` may contain some of the not yet released things.